# Customizing QPrintDialog - Need to remove access to disk storage

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I need to customize the QPrintDialog in the Qt framework. The default view has controls that give access to local storage on the device. All access to local disks must be disabled on the dialog.

This software runs on Linux.

Is it safe to iterate over child widgets on the QPrintDialog and disable or remove all controls used for accessing the disk?

Example:

```
    auto childrenList = printDialog->children ();
    
      for(auto obj : childrenList)
      {
        if(obj->isWidgetType ())
        {
          ...
    
          if(qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(obj))
          {
             qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(obj)->removeItem (1);
             qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(obj)->setEnabled (false);
          }
    
          if(qobject_cast<QLabel*>(obj))
          {
            qobject_cast<QLabel*>(obj)->setEnabled (false);
            qobject_cast<QLabel*>(obj)->setText ("");
            qobject_cast<QLabel*>(obj)->setParent (parent);
          }
    
          if(qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(obj))
          {
            qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(obj)->setEnabled (false);
            qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(obj)->setText ("");
            qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(obj)->setParent (parent);
            qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(obj)->hide ();
          }
          
          ...
    }
}
```

--

Comment: Are you referring to the print to file functionality?

Comment: @musicamante Any widget that accesses the file-system. Only the USB devices should be accessible.

Comment: Please clarify what controls you're referring to. As far as I can remember, the standard QPrintDialog on Linux only provides access to the file system for the "print to file" functionality (the line input for the path and the QFileDialog for browsing), while all other "controls" (*widgets*) are just printing related (page range, copies, etc.). If what you want is to limit access to specific *paths* in the file dialog or the line input, then that's a quite different story, and while it may be possible to partially limit access to removable devices, doing it reliably may be almost impossible.

Comment: @musicamante Using the example code I posted the controls used to navigate the file system can be removed but obviously it won't work if the controls change.  We do ship the hardware and software so we don't need to be concerned about where the software is running.

Comment: I still don't understand to what controls you're referring to. QPrintDialog has *many* widgets, including labels and combos that have absolutely *nothing* to do with file system access. Even assuming you have complete control over the *current* environment, arbitrarily disabling/hiding widgets just based on their types is a terrible choice if not done with complete awareness. Please take your time and answer what I asked above more carefully, possibly by [edit]ing your question and providing related images that may make easier to us to understand to what you're referring to.

Comment: @musicamante, I want to remove the printer name and output file control. If they can be disabled I believe that'll be acceptable.

Comment: The printer names have nothing to do with local file access, and it's not clear what "output file control" means. Please, for the last time, answer *more specifically* to all that has been asked, we cannot help you if you use unspecific terms or ambiguous descriptions.